# Microsoft Graph Api User.Read.All Not granted for my domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the following error or status `Not granted for my domain`. see the attached document
[image]
**Is this because my role is `User`?**

I tried to find who is Azure AD `Global Administrator`?

I followed the following steps:

1. Log into the Azure Portal `(https://portal.azure.com)`.
2. Click on `Azure Active Directory`
3. Click on `Roles and administrators`
4. Click on `Global administrator`
5. Under `Global administrator` it says `Microsoft Office 365 Portal`

what does it mean?
How can I or someone else in organization become `Global administrator`?
I want `API permissions->User.Read.All` Not granted for mydomain

**PS: My email is `work email`.**

**Update 1**
My role is user
[image]

**Update 2**
`Global administrator - Assignments` say's `Microsoft Office 365 Portal` is my Admin. How to get these credentials?
[image]

Comment: What is your role in that tenant?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron `User`

Answer (score 27):

[image: Grant consent screenshot]

I was similiarly frustrated here: it's very hard to spot, however you'll notice that the 'grant admin consent for -' is reset on every update to permissions.

Therefore: simply re-tick this and wait a few seconds for the warnings to disappear.

I too thought I was missing a step elsewhere, very misleading!

Comment: took me several hours to figure this out. Many thanks!!!!

Comment: @jersoft no worries! I can't believe some of the work flows required for what I think is fairly standard asks.

Comment: You da man! Saved the task.

Answer (score 1):

For `User.Read.All` permission you should have `Admin Consent` which a `User` cannot avail.

You should have either `Global Admin` or `Application administrator` credentials.

*Permission Required:*

[image]

Please refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) `Permission details`

*Admin Credentials:*

[image]

For Admin credentials details refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-40)

*Office 365 Admin Role Assignment:*

[image]

Hope this will help. Let me know if you have any more concern.

Comment: It says `Microsoft Office 365 Portal` is my admin. How to get these credentials?

Comment: It says mean what? As per my experience you should have that role. Please refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent). In screen shot you have tried with `delegated permission` also try with `Application permission`

Comment: `Global administrator - Assignments` say's `Microsoft Office 365 Portal` is my Admin.

Comment: If so, in that case add your email as `Global Admin` On office 365 portal. I have updated my answer how you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure** that if you're the only one or just opened the account that you are an admin on Microsoft 365.

1. You will need to add a TXT record in your DNS settings (F.e. Route53 - AWS) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/become-the-admin?view=o365-worldwide

Once that is verified you will automatically be a global administrator and then you will have access to all admin features.

2. Go back to Azure and then just click on the small hard to see in grey here:

[image]